# If Admin.isvalid then it enables the admin roles in next page if user.isvalid then it give the user roles in next page asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

When user logged in then it checks either if it is admin or user then it enables the controls accordingly in next page in asp.net c#

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users Where Name ='" txtusername.Text + "' AND Password='" + txtpassword.Text + "'", con);

con.Open();

    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      if (sdr.Read() == true)
    {
        try
           bool Admin = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["Admin"]);
            isadmin = Admin;
            Response.Redirect("InserRecord.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: you can save it in a session variable like Session["Admin"] = true;

Answer (score 0):

put it in a session variable

```
Session["Admin"] = true;
```

then in next page load you can put like:

```
var admin = Session["Admin"] as bool;

if(admin){
//enable controls.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a session variable to store whether the user is an admin or not and then any page can reference it and act accordingly.

```
SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      if (sdr.Read() == true)
    {
        try
           bool Admin = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["Admin"]);
            Session["IsAdmin"] = Admin;
            Response.Redirect("InserRecord.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: how to access it in next page?

Comment: @shanmuhammad as the answer other than mine showed: 

var Admin = Session["IsAdmin"]